# Sorting data on google sheets chart

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, graph, charts

I have unsorted data in the sheet and I would like to show a chart with sorted data.

Here is an example:

[image]

---

I would like the chart to be sorted ascending, by compensation.

How can this be done with the data being structured as on the picture?

Comment: It appears this is a major limitation in Google Sheets and there is no direct way to fix this! What a shame

Answer (score 24, accepted):

move and sort your individual tables to Sheet2 with: **`=SORT(Sheet1!A3:B6,2,1)`**

[image]

then construct your chart from there:

[image]

Comment: Tnx, this works perfectly. Is there a way to avoid duplicating the data and do something in the chart editor that would lead to the sameresult?

Comment: @user3760419 chart editor does not have capabilities to do so.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, either, because you have to create a new sheet for the sorted data. What if the original data on Sheet1 changes? You have to update the information on Sheet2 every time it changes? Not very practical.

Comment: @OMA fx on Sheet2 references source data directly so any change on Sheet1 will lead to immediate recalculation of Sheet2 - basic knowledge

Answer (score -4):

Just sort the table by the column that should drive the order. After that, the graph will be adjusted.

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking. He/she said "with the data being structured as on the picture", not with a completely different sorting order.